# Why doesn't this for-loop execute?

Tags: c++, for-loop, getline

I'm writing a program for an exercise that will read data from a file and format it to be readable. So far, I have a bit of code that will separate a header from the data that goes under it. Here it is:

```
int main() {
    ifstream in("records.txt");
    ofstream out("formatted_records.txt");
    vector<string> temp;
    vector<string> headers;
    for (int i = 0; getline(in,temp[i]); ++i) {
        static int k = -1;
        if (str_isalpha(temp[i])) {
            headers[++k] = temp[i];
            temp.erase(temp.begin() + i);
        }
        else {
            temp[i] += "," + headers[k];
        }
    }
}
```

(`str_isalpha()` is just a function that applies `isalpha()` to every character in a string.) Now, the for-loop in this program doesn't execute, and I can't figure out why. Does anybody know?

EDIT: As suggested, I changed it to

```
string line;
for (int i = 0; getline(in,line); ++i) {
    temp.push_back(line);
```

Still skips the for-loop altogether.

Comment: is that a comma in the getline parameter?

Comment: Yeah, that is how arguments gets separated in a function, is it not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the loop still doesn't run after ensuring that you're reading into a valid string reference, then you should check that the stream you're reading from is valid. The stream will be invalid if the file doesn't exist or if you lack permission to read it, for instance. When the stream isn't valid, `getline` won't read anything. Its return value is the same stream, and when converted to `bool`, it evaluates as `false`. Check the stream's status before proceeding.

```
ifstream in("records.txt");
if (!in.is_open()) {
  std::cerr << "Uh-oh.\n";
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this turned out to be the problem.

Answer (score 5):

`vector<string> temp;` makes an *empty* vector.  When you then try to read into `temp[0]`, that  is undefined behavior.  You should pass as `getline`'s second argument a separate `string` variable, say `string foo;` before the loop, then `temp.push_back(foo);` as the first instruction in the loop's body.